# Cannot browse white icons in Mac OS Monterey

Tags: icons, thumbnails, automator, macos-monterey

When I try to browser my white icons with transparent backgrounds, I get this:

[image]

Finder adds it's own white backgrounds behind my icons. It makes my design work impossible. Similair threads have been made in the past, where the chosen solution was to create and automator script that looks like this:

[image]

However, the "add thumbnail icons to image files" option is missing in Mac OS Monterey. Anyone has a fix, a workaround? This is quite a widespread problem as it makes working with white icons on Mac simply impossible.

Many many thanks, any info would be appreciated!